# How to change the background color when running in the GNOME Terminal?

Tags: faces, terminal-emacs, colors

I have added `(set-background-color "blue")` to my `~/.emacs` (just for test purposes). When I run Emacs in windowed mode this makes the background color blue (as expected), but when I run Emacs in terminal mode in the GNOME Terminal (with or without an associated X display), the background color remains what it was when running the shell I used to start Emacs, which is black.

Why doesn't `(set-background-color "blue")` work when I run Emacs in the GNOME Terminal, and what must I do instead to change the background color? Is it possible to do this in Emacs or do I need to change the color scheme of the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to review your question; it appears to have some confusion about the difference between black and blue.

You can read the documentation for `set-background-color` (or any other function) by typing `C-h f`, and entering the function name when prompted. For reference here is the help for `set-background-color`:

```
set-background-color is an interactive and byte-compiled function
defined in frame.el.gz.

Signature
(set-background-color COLOR-NAME)

Documentation
Set the background color of the selected frame to COLOR-NAME.

When called interactively, prompt for the name of the color to use.
To get the frame's current background color, use frame-parameters.
```

Note in particular that this function sets the background color of the *currently selected frame*. But during startup when your init file is run, there are no frames yet.

Instead of calling this function, you want to set the default frame parameters:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "blue"))
```

See [chapter 21.11 Frame Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frame-Parameters.html) of the Emacs manual for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the notification. I've fixed that error now.

Comment: Changing to `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "blue"))` doesn't have any effect. The background color of Emacs is still blue when running in windowed mode but black when running in terminal mode.